# Magmi importing configurable product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magmi

Im trying to import products using magmi. I can import simple products. But not able to import configurable products. I tried finding sample csv files to import configurable products. But I couldnt find right one. I know im having problem with my csv file. Can anyone help me to resolve my issue? Here is my csv file.

```
sku,store,attributeset,type,category,root_category,product_websites,activation_information,color,computer_manufacturers,contrast_ratio,cost,country_of_manufacture,country_orgin,cpu_speed,created_at,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,description,dimension,enable_googlecheckout,finish,gallery,gender,gift_message_available,harddrive_speed,hardrive,has_options,image,image_label,in_depth,manufacturer,max_resolution,media_gallery,megapixels,memory,meta_description,meta_keyword,meta_title,minimal_price,model,msrp,msrp_display_actual_price_type,msrp_enabled,name,news_from_date,news_to_date,options_container,page_layout,price,processor,ram_size,required_options,response_time,room,screensize,shape,shirt_size,shoe_size,shoe_type,short_description,small_image,small_image_label,special_from_date,special_price,special_to_date,status,tax_class_id,thumbnail,thumbnail_label,updated_at,url_key,url_path,visibility,weight,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,links_related_sku,links_related_position,links_crosssell_sku,links_crosssell_position,links_upsell_sku,links_upsell_position,associated_sku,associated_default_qty,associated_position,tier_price_website,tier_price_customer_group,tier_price_qty,tier_price_price,group_price_website,group_price_customer_group,group_price_price,media_attribute_id,media_image,media_lable,media_position,media_is_disabled,custom_option_store,custom_option_type,custom_option_title,custom_option_is_required,custom_option_price,custom_option_sku,custom_option_max_characters,custom_option_sort_order,custom_option_row_title,custom_option_row_price,custom_option_row_sku,custom_option_row_sort,super_products_sku,super_attribute_code,super_attribute_option,super_attribute_price_corr,simples_skus,configurable_attributes
999-Black,,Default,simple,,,base,,Black,,,,,,,4/23/2013 9:29,,,,,test,,1,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Use config,Use config,My IS test-Black,,,Block after Info Column,,122,,,0,,,,,,,,tewst,,,,,,1,0,,,4/23/2013 9:29,my-is-test-black,my-is-test-black.html,1,100,100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
999-Blue,,Default,simple,,,base,,Blue,,,,,,,4/23/2013 9:30,,,,,test,,1,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Use config,Use config,My IS test-Blue,,,Block after Info Column,,122,,,0,,,,,,,,tewst,,,,,,1,0,,,4/23/2013 9:30,my-is-test-blue,my-is-test-blue.html,1,100,100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
999-Brown,,Default,simple,,,base,,Brown,,,,,,,4/23/2013 9:30,,,,,test,,1,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Use config,Use config,My IS test-Brown,,,Block after Info Column,,122,,,0,,,,,,,,tewst,,,,,,1,0,,,4/23/2013 9:30,my-is-test-brown,my-is-test-brown.html,1,100,100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
999-Green,,Default,simple,,,base,,Green,,,,,,,4/23/2013 9:30,,,,,test,,1,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Use config,Use config,My IS test-Green,,,Block after Info Column,,122,,,0,,,,,,,,tewst,,,,,,1,0,,,4/23/2013 9:30,my-is-test-green,my-is-test-green.html,1,100,100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
999,,Default,configurable,Furniture/Living Room,Root Catalog,base,,,,,,,,,4/23/2013 9:29,,,,,test,,1,,,,,,,1,no_selection,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Use config,Use config,My IS test,,,Block after Info Column,,122,,,1,,,,,,,,tewst,no_selection,,,,,1,0,no_selection,,4/23/2013 9:30,my-is-test,my-is-test.html,4,,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"999-Black,999-Blue,999-Brown,999-Green",color,"Black,Blue,Brown,Green",,"999-Black,999-Blue,999-Brown,999-Green",color
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have the `Configurable Item processor` plugin enabled.  It's listed under the `Itemprocessors` section in Magmi.

Also make sure the settings for the `Configurable Item processor` plugin are as follows:

`Perform simples/configurable link` set to `Yes`

`auto match simples skus before configurable` set to `No` (since you are specifying the matches in the `simples_skus` column.

Comment: @Palanikumar, where do you map column type into in the column mapper? I'm trying with type_id, product_type_id, product_type but none is working.

Comment: @Axel: How can i import cross sell and upsell products using magmi, i am getting an error like, https://snag.gy/gCGoBk.jpg how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to edit the file magmi/plugins/base/itemprocessors/configurables/magmi_configurableprocessor.php changing the line:

```
        //if no entry found, create one
        if($psaid==NULL)
        {
            $sql="INSERT INTO `$cpsa` (`product_id`,`attribute_id`,`position`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            //inserting new options
            $psaid=$this->insert($sql,array($pid,$attrid,$idx));    
        }
```

for

```
//if no entry found, create one
        if($psaid==NULL)
        {
            $sql="INSERT INTO `$cpsa` (`product_id`,`attribute_id`,`position`) VALUES (:a, :b, :c)";
            $data = array(
                'a' => $pid,
                'b' => $attrid,
                'c' =>$idx,
            );
            //inserting new options
            $psaid=$this->insert($sql,$data);
        }
```